# Nginx subdomain and domain pointing to the same files in root

Tags: nginx

I have my-domain.com and prod.my-domain.com and I have created the following configuration settings for both.

#### prod.my-domain.com

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name prod.my-domain.com;

      location / {
         root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
         index index.php index.html index.htm;
       }
       location /prod{
            autoindex on;
       }

      error_page 404  /404.html;
            location  = /404.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/index/html/prod/;
      }

     error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
          location = /50.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
     }

   location ~ \.php$ {
         fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
         error_page  404  /path/to/404.htm;
         fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_index  index.php;
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

#### my-domain.com

```
 server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  my-domain.com;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
       error_page  404  /path/to/404.htm;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

But, whichever URL I enter takes me where all the files for `my-domain.com` are stored. 
I would like to see the contents for `root /usr/share/nginx/index/html/prod/` when I visit 
`prod.my-domain.com` but, it takes me to root `/usr/share/nginx/index/html/`

Comment: The `root` is the same in both server configurations for location `/`, is this a mistake on your end?

Comment: @AhmadSherif Yes, that I forgot to replace here because I had been trying various ways and none worked. Anyway, this solved the answer http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-host-ghost-on-a-nginx-subdomain/ I was forces to create two folders for the main site and prod as `main.site.com` & `prod.site.com` 

Maybe this answer could help for new questions